# is it valid to use thread.sleep and repaint to create my first java game?

Tags: java, thread-sleep

I am trying to make a simple java game using alphabets (car game),
i am using thread.sleep() in a while loop and repaint method to change the axis of elements
like cars, enemies, fuels etc., in the game.

I can see the page flickers during the game.
is this approach not correct? how do i make the game work without flickering?

Thanks,
Balan

Comment: Do you do this in swing? Don't send the event dispatch thread to sleep but use a worker/timer/executor.

Comment: Using Swing for a game is not a very good idea. Try LWJGL or something similar.

Comment: @Thomas : Actually i just use drawString and drawImage functions in a Applet, not swing. I will checkout the worker/timer/executor you have mentioned about.

Comment: @MightyPork : I was not sure on where to start gaming in Java, thanks for your suggestion. I will check out LWJGL.